# Error: Missing credentials in config in my Angular 4 application

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, credentials, amazon-cognito

I'm developing a web application which uses AWS services backend size. In this moment I use AWS Cognito (User Pool) to manage user sessions.

I would like a method that will help me to have all users of a User Pool so I can show them in my application. 
This is the code written by me:

```
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

var params = {
  UserPoolId: environment.userPoolId,
  AttributesToGet: [
    'username',
  ],

};

cognitoidentity.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

unfortunately I always fall in the case of error and the console prints this:

```
Error: Missing credentials in config
    at Request.extractError (json.js:48)
    at Request.callListeners (sequential_executor.js:105)
    at Request.emit (sequential_executor.js:77)
    at Request.emit (request.js:683)
    at Request.transition (request.js:22)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (state_machine.js:14)
    at state_machine.js:26
    at Request.<anonymous> (request.js:38)
    at Request.<anonymous> (request.js:685)
    at Request.callListeners (sequential_executor.js:115)
```

I tried in all ways the method (even using global variables) but unfortunately I could not get it running. Does anyone know how I can fix the problem and how do I provide credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the ways you can supply your credentials in order of recommendation:

1. Loaded from AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles for Amazon EC2 (if running on Amazon EC2)
2. Loaded from the shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials)
3. Loaded from environment variables
4. Loaded from a JSON file on disk

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Load credentials and set region from JSON file
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');

//Inline
 var creds = new AWS.Credentials('akid', 'secret', 'session');
```

Or you can use the Credential provider chain that will search all the providers mentioned above.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CredentialProviderChain.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html